# LINQ (EF) query property of list of grandchildren as list

Tags: entity-framework, linq, ef-core-7.0

Trying to add a projection where I get Ids from a list from a list.

Given a relationship like:

-> accounts

--> users

---> cars

----> id

Single level, ids of users, works:

```cs
builder.Entity<AccountModel>()
.WithProjection(x => x.UsersIds, x => x.Users.Select(y => y.Id).ToList());
```

But I need ids of cars, and I can't seem to put together the right query today:

```cs
    .WithProjection(x => x.CarsIds, x => x.Users.SelectMany(y => y.Cars.Select(z => z.Id)).ToList());
```

Trying throws an error like:

> The LINQ expression 'y => y.Cars.Select(z => z.Id)' could not be translated

**Alternative example** as suggested by Danyliv:

```cs
_context.Accounts.Select(a => new 
{
    CarsIds = a.Users.SelectMany(y => y.Cars.Select(z => z.Id)).ToList()
})
```

> The LINQ expression 'x => x.Users' could not be translated.

I am trying to avoid pulling in the entire list of users and cars when querying the accounts, but I want to know what ids for each of these things exist at the account level.

---

*Update*

Tried:

```cs
   .WithProjection(x => x.CarsIds, x => x.Users.SelectMany(y => y.Cars).Select(z => z.Id).ToList())
```

> The LINQ expression 'y => y.Cars' could not be translated

So maybe SelectMany doesn't play nice with EF?

Comment: Nobody instead of me knows what `WithProjection` do. Edit question and rephrase without using this extension.

Comment: try this `builder.Entity<AccountModel>()
    .WithProjection(x => x.UsersIds, 
        x => x.Users.SelectMany(y => y.Cars).Select(z => z.Id).ToList());`

Comment: @Basharmal updated after trying that

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm not sure how to do that, this is the only place I try something like this

Comment: retrieve the car IDs in two separate queries. First, retrieve the user IDs, and then retrieve the car IDs separately`builder.Entity<AccountModel>()
    .WithProjection(x => x.UsersIds, x => x.Users.Select(y => y.Id).ToList());

builder.Entity<AccountModel>()
    .WithProjection(x => x.CarsIds, 
        x => x.Users.SelectMany(y => y.Cars).Select(z => z.Id).ToList());`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv tried to add another example, is this what you were getting at?

Comment: How `x.Users` is mapped to database?

Comment: @RandyHall, I have modified example without `WithProjection` check how it works for you. Also notice that All properties used in this `Select` should be mapped to database.